# Will multiple calls to Eloquent dynamic property hit the database multiple times?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#dynamic-properties

```
class Phone extends Eloquent {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}

$phone = Phone::find(1);
```

Now, if I then do something like this:

```
echo $phone->user->email;
echo $phone->user->name;
echo $phone->user->nickname;
```

Will Eloquent make a database call for every time I use the `->user` dynamic property? Or is this smart enough to cache the user on the first call?

Comment: One iteration will make a call to `Phone` and `User`. Multiple iterations you have to eager load. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: I believe that the first reference to `$phone->user` will load the `User` model complete with all attributes local to that model.  Presuming that `email`, `name`, and `nickname` are stored in `User`, then this would result in only two database queries (one for phone, another for the user).  Try it out: after these statements, run `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` to see the exact queries made.

Comment: @cerebriform - `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` gave me my answer: It -does- cache the database call. Even when I access it three times like in the example above only one extra database query is used to fetch the `User` object. Thanks for pointing out how to see the query log. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, the `user` attribute on the `$phone` object will be lazy loaded, but it will only be loaded once.

Keep in mind, as well, that once the object is loaded, it does not reflect any changes to the underlying table unless you manually reload the relationship using the `load` method.

The following code illustrates the example:

```
$phone = Phone::find(1);

// first use of user attribute triggers lazy load
echo $phone->user->email;

// get that user outta here.
User::destroy($phone->user->id);

// echoes the name just fine, even though the record doesn't exist anymore
echo $phone->user->name;

// manually reload the relationship
$phone->load('user');

// now will show null, since the user was deleted and the relationship was reloaded
var_export($phone->user);
```

Comment: This means that even if I used eager loading to get the same data I'd still get two database calls when I'm fetching only one object. Perfectly summarize my questions I had about this. Thank you.

Comment: @thomthom Yes, eager loading will create at a minimum two database calls. However, it prevents the n+1 issue. If you did `$phones = Phone::all();`, and then foreach through all the phone objects and displayed the user name, it would do one query to get all the phones, and then a separate user query for every single loop iteration (n+1). However, if you eager load by doing `$phones = Phone::with('user')->get();`, and run the same foreach, that will only make 2 database calls total, one for the phones, and one for all the related users.